# Partition lattice properties and an invariant.

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, combinatorial-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics

I am trying to guess the value of the beta invariant of the partition lattice $\pi_4$ if I know the following information:

For any matroid $M,$ I know that

1- $\beta(M) \geq 0.$

2- $\beta(M) > 0$ if and only if $M$is connected and is not a loop.

3- If $e \in E$ is neither a coloop nor a loop,

$$\beta (M) = \beta (M - e) + \beta (M /e).$$

4- $\beta (M^*) = \beta (M)$ except when $M$ is a coloop or a loop.

I also tried to calculate it using: If $e$ is not a loop  $\beta(M) = (-1)^{r(M) -1} \sum_{F\in L, e \notin F} \mu_M(\emptyset, F)$ but I got that the answer is 3 and by a little online Googling I understood that the answer is 1. In my calculations I used the idea that the lattice of flats of the matroid $M(K_4)$ is isomorphic to the partition lattice $\pi_4$ and I know from the drawing of $K_4$ that it does not have loops so I assumed also that $\pi_4$ also does not have loops, that is why I used the formula above in calculations. I also know that the Hasse Diagram of $\pi_4$ is the one given in the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isqkb.png)

Any clarification on how to just guess it from the 4 points above will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a strategy to tackle this problem that I think could work is try to compute the beta invariant of a minor of $M(K_4)$ (note that these correspond to cycle matroids of graphic minors of $K_4$). Then you could combine these using the recursive property of Crapo's beta invariant in bullet point 3. Perhaps that is easier than to directly compute it? Note that using the recursive structure only is not sufficient, since you have no bullet point telling you an exact non-zero value for $\beta$.

However, I do think the answer is probably that $\beta(M(K_4))=2$. A result from Sooyeon Lee's PhD thesis (https://egrove.olemiss.edu/etd/1772/) implies that if $M$ a wheel, which $M(K_4)$ is, then $\beta(M) = r(M)-1$. Since $r(M(K_4)) = 3$, this would imply the above. There is probably more a lot more useful information in the thesis, would you be interested.

Comment: As I said, you need something more than just the four bullet points. You need to know an actual positive value for some matroid/lattice that you can use in conjunction with point 3. One such thing is the formula you have, but I am sure there is more you can use if you have access to White's book.

Comment: It is likely you should use previous theorem, or at least some definitions/observations. For instance the observation before 7.3.1 as well as that proposition could likely be used. This is common in most textbooks. Using theorem 7.3.2 doesn't mean don't use anything else. If you want, I could try to write up a solution tomorrow, assuming this is not homework @Hope

Comment: ok, I see your point, if you want to write up a solution that will be helpful, if not that is fine also, whatever you want.